# nginx Angular js hide http url

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, nginx

How can i hide my http url in angular js.
Lets say I dont want to show https://www.example.com/api/v1/page. in below snippet
If we cannot hide,Is there any way to encrypt it.
Thanks in advance!!

```
 myApp.service('dataService', function($http,$q) {
                     delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
                     this.getData = function() {
                        deferred = $q.defer();
                        $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/page',
                            params: 'limit=10, sort_by=created:desc',
                            headers: {'Authorization': 'Token token=xxxxYYYYZzzz'}
                        }).success(function(data){
                            // With the data succesfully returned, we can resolve promise and we can access it in controller
                            deferred.resolve();
                        }).error(function(){
                             alert("error");
                             //let the function caller know the error
                             deferred.reject(error);
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
                     }
                   });
```

Comment: Why do want to hide it ? Even if you managed to hide the Url, it can be intercepted in the network calls.

Comment: Ok.. So you mean to say I can only protect it on my service level not on the js level ?

Comment: I'm saying even it can be seen in the browser's Inspector tools or with some intercepting tools or extension. If your motive is to hide your APIs from users than that's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info  Abhishek..